# Matrix function

Tags: r, matrix, melt

How can I get a function which takes a matrix and a vector as input and does the following

```
v<-c(1,2,4)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

The outout shall be:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    2    5
[4,]    3    6
[5,]    3    6
[6,]    3    6
[7,]    3    6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rep` to replicate the rows of the matrix ('m1') by the vector ('v')

```
m1[rep(1:nrow(m1), v),]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    2    5
#[4,]    3    6
#[5,]    3    6
#[6,]    3    6
#[7,]    3    6
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
v<-c(1,2,4)
```

Comment: @sdji You showed a matrix and a vector.  Are you getting the same error using the data I used?

Comment: get Error: long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:137
..is there a way to do this on really really larg matri with 10 millions row

Comment: @sdji Which version of R are you using?  I am using the `R 3.2.1`

Comment: me too also using that version..is there a package or is it doble with MATRIX..

Comment: mean the package matrix with the capital m

Comment: @sdji In the question, you posted a minimal example and expected output.  My answer was based on that.  It didn't mention anything about how big the dataset is.

Comment: I can't confirm the error message. When I tested @akrun's solution it produced the desired output.

Comment: @sdji Using the same example, worked with `Matrix` also. `m2 <- Matrix(1:6, ncol=2);m2[rep(1:nrow(m2), v),]#
7 x 2 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"`

Comment: @sdji Also, if the matrix is really big, then could you split it up and then try. i.e. Just for an example `n <- 5;  m2 <- m1[seq_len(n),]; m2[rep(1:nrow(m2), v[seq_len(n)]),]` and repeat this for the remaining rows and `rbind`.